# Display output of the design automation API in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

Using the Inventor Design Automation API I would like to change several parameters in my model and display these changes in the Forge Viewer (web).

What would be the best solution to achieve this? 
I was think of saving the to changed model as a new file, upload this file and use the Model Derivative API to generate a SVF. Then somehow get the new URN back to the client and load it in the viewer.

But I feel like there must be a simpler way, plus I'm not too sure about the performance of this solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Design Automation APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2) are meant to execute self-contained, potentially long-running tasks, or "background jobs".

If you're interested in *real-time* (or *semi-real-time*) preview of changes to a parametric model, these APIs are not the best choice I'm afraid. Like you said, in that case you'd need to submit a set (or multiple sets) of parameters, generate one or more output files, run them through the [Model Derivative APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2), and wait for the translated outputs using [Webhooks APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1).

Comment: Thanks Petr,

Do you have a suggestion on how to accomplish this? We've also looked to Fusion 360, but found the documentation to be lacking in this regard.
Are you aware of the LimbForge customer Story in Autodesk? They seem to have implemented a similar solution. (https://forge.autodesk.com/customer-stories/limbforge)

We have these kind of scenarios:
https://viscon.elfskot.cloud/nl/configure/Vitra-belt-conveyor
The conveyor can be configured in multiple dimensions and we would like to fill the parameters and show the result.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with LimbForge. If there are not too many permutations of your input parameters, perhaps you could pre-process all the possible variations in Forge and load them to the client based on the current config. Would that work for you?

Comment: Alternatively, if some input parameters only cause a change in one specific component without affecting other parts of the model, you could consider a [multi-model workflow](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/model-aggregation-with-view-data-api-exposed.html), swapping models of specific components based on the input.

Comment: Sure. Let me know how it goes :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i want to embed such a viewer on my website, i want to know,
1-do you upload files on you own host? or on Autodesk cloud?
2-can i get parts details such as dimension and material from viewer to calculate price dynamically using BOM? or i have to create a price database depending on variations?
3-@ Johannes Heesterman, what is the work-flow that you currently using on your website?
4- is this possible to change the texture or color of some parts in this viewer?

Comment: 1. you need to put the file in a forge bucket in order to process it for viewing, see (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/)
2. through the viewer javascript api you can get these details or through model derivative (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-metadata-from-source-file/)
4. yes totally doable, some things are even provided by the viewer js api which uses three.js under the hood so allows you to customise a lot.